# Fsharp - types compilation error

Tags: f#, filesystems, fsharpchart

I am new to F#, and I'd love to get some help :)

I have ? compilation error on this code, and I can't figure it out:

```
printfn "Please enter the path for the Jack file/s directory"
let dir = System.Console.ReadLine()
let jackFiles : List<String> = (new List<String>())
dir
|> Directory.GetFiles
|> Seq.iteri(fun file -> if ((Path.GetExtension(file)).Equals(".jack")) then JackFiles.Add(file))
```

The compiler shouts this error:

> This expression was expected to have type `string->unit` but here has type `unit`

about the `if ((Path.GetExtension(file)).Equals(".jack")) then JackFiles.Add(file))` part...

Why is it wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function argument to `Seq.iteri` requires two arguments and should have type `(int -> 'T -> unit)`. Its file parameter is inferred to have type `int` and therefore your `if` statement should have type `string -> unit` but actually has type `unit`, hence the error.

It looks like you don't require the `int` argument so you can use `Seq.iter` instead.

However it looks like what you're trying to do could be done using something similar to:

```
let jackFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jack")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Lee's answer, I have several remarks:

- One way to avoid your error is to use `for` loop instead of `Seq.iter(i)`. I find `for` loop is more readable without having to deal with closure.
- `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` exists in F# under the name `ResizeArray`. You even have [ResizeArray module](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.powerpack/microsoft.fsharp.collections.resizearray.html) in F# PowerPack with all necessary high-order functions.
- One should you `=` instead of `obj.Equals`.

Applying above comments, your solution looks like:

```
let jackFiles = ResizeArray()
for file in Directory.GetFiles(dir) do
    if Path.GetExtension(file) = ".jack" then jackFiles.Add(file)
```

Comment: Thanks! But why using = instead of obj.Equals ?

Comment: @cookya: they same the same meaning here, and `=` is shorter and more functional.